# Barplot pvalues over specific bars in R

Tags: r, plot, p-value

I want to put pvalues over barplot but represent them by an asterisk (* is pval = .05 to .01, ** asterisk between .009 to .001 and *** is smaller than .001.
Lets assume I have this random data called scores and barplot them and do test comparing 100 to 85,88, and 82. 30 and 76 are internal controls ( no test test). I extracted pvalues and stored in empty vector represented by pval. How can I convert the pval numbers and put over the corresponding bars? I am just at a lose on this. Maybe some loop and text? I want something where 100 is control, 85 - 82 should have pval over them and 30 and 76 nothing over them.

```
scores<- c(100, 85, 88, 82, 30, 76);
barplot(scores);
pvalues;
[1] 3.826535e-05 1.038895e-01 4.257805e-05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the returned value from `barplot` to get the x-values of the bars and then use `text` to place the asterisks.

```
## Sample Data
scores<- c(100, 85, 88, 82, 30, 76)
pvalues <- c(NA, 3.826535e-05, 1.038895e-01, 4.257805e-05, NA, NA)

## Get asterisks
barText <- ifelse(pvalues < 1e-3, "***", ifelse(pvalues < 1e-2, "**", ifelse(pvalues < 5e-2, "*", "")))
barText <- ifelse(is.na(barText), "", barText)

## Make plot
breaks <- barplot(scores)
text(breaks, scores+2, labels=barText)
```

[image]

Comment: @ nongkrong, this is what I was looking for. Sorry for not upvoting sooner, had to fit this and code it slightly different to fit my very complex problem. However, thanks to you, this got me to my final answer. Thanks a bunch.